# Custom name instead of IP address to access Flask Applications on remote server

Tags: python, flask, ubuntu-20.04

I have a Flask Web Application running on Ubuntu 20.04 server
I run it as follows -

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

I want to access it with an app name -
`http://[app.name]:5000` instead of `http://0.0.0.0:5000` i.e., using the IP address of the server.

I have tried the following -
Changed the hostname from

```
$ sudo nano /etc/hostname
```

And also changed the `hosts` file

```
$ sudo nano /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1 app.name
[ip address] app.name
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

I have restarted the server and changed the following in `main`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.config['SERVER_NAME']='app.name:5000'
    app.run()
```

This approach doesn't work, can you help me find what the problem is?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to change the `SERVER_NAME` - 0.0.0.0 means that it accepts connections from anywhere (as opposed to 127.0.0.1 accepting only localhost connections).

Your `/etc/hosts` file looks correct - as long as it contains that `127.0.0.1 app.name` entry, you're good to go.

Then in your app file, keep

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Here's some sample code:

test.py:

```py
from flask import *

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hi():
  return "bye"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1  app.name
```

Accessing http://app.name:5000/ works.

Comment: this doesn't work for me. I tried this exact same thing again, this is on a remote ubuntu server

Comment: @heisenbug29 Maybe something here might help: https://serverfault.com/questions/452268/hosts-file-ignored-how-to-troubleshoot. Also, restarting your browser (if you haven't tried that yet) might also fix the problem

Comment: we are doing an app.run('0.0.0.0') this means the IP address of the machine right? And in the etc/hosts file we are setting the app name on localhost? Why not on the IP of the machine, how will others access it

Comment: 0.0.0.0 just means that it can accept a connection from anyone, not just the local machine.